# Maven Checkstyle Site

Tags: maven, checkstyle

this question seems to be quite common, but I really couldn't make it work from the existing answers. 
I have a simple maven project without any complicated configuration for deploying etc. and want to generate a Maven CheckStyle report when hitting "mvn site".

My pom.xml is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestProjekt</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>TestProjekt</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>mychecks.xml</configLocation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>
```

I've got mychecks.xml in the root directory of the project (next to the pom.xml). The problem is, when I hit "mvn site", nothing happens at all (apart from maven writing a few lines about BUILD SUCCESS). I read that I have to place the mychecks.xml in a directory named "resources" or something like that, but that didn't work either.

Does someone have a hint what to do to make "mvn site" generate a checkstyle rport (and where to find it)? Any kind of help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well no wonder it didn't work! The docs on the maven site about the plugin are really outdated (and quite meager too). I'm wondering why they don't even put a marker on their site that the info is outdated when changing important config options.

You can find the real config for Maven 3 and CheckStyle at 
http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/maven.htm#Site-Project-Reports-Mvn3

It's german, but just ignore it. The XML speaks for itself.

Comment: The syntax on the linked page is invalid with version 3.3 of maven-site-plugin. <reportPlugins> cannot be nested under configuration any more. See section with 'New Configuration' from Maven site

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue is not with `maven checkstyle plugin` as much as running the `site` goal in `maven 3`.  There are **different** site plugin versions to generate site information for [maven 2](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/) and [maven 3](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin-3.0-beta-3/) and the plugin page [documents](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/migrate.html) this.

In fact, [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-and-site-plugin.html) maven wiki page talks about it too.

Comment: Info at the deadlinks is probably at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html